# Performance tool for Web Single Page Application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

Please, assist me on this one. 
Project is for Web Single Page Application that does not provide different urls for different view. Everything loads by clicking within one screen. I was asked to find performance tool to test such application.

I will not be able to get HP Loadrunner or any such tool that is in the same price range. Maybe there is an open source or how to use JIRA for my project?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do performance testing of single page application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239040/how-to-do-performance-testing-of-single-page-application)

Answer (score 0):

When you click somewhere, even if screen doesn't change, browser sends relevant HTTP Request (usually GET or POST). JMeter acts on protocol level, it doesn't actually "render" the page or execute JavaScript but it can send any HTTP Request.

So you should be able to record all the requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and replay them with larger number of threads according to your load test scenario.

You can use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to visualize request and response details and [JMeter Assertions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) to ensure that test actually does what it should do.